# what is the meaning of unknown firebase projects in my account

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-console

I recently created a new gmail account for a firebase project for my client, added a billing method, and created one simple hosting project and left is there for a while.

Now when I come back to the account to deploy a work, I found out unknown projects which I am dead sure to have never created in the billing page, with even some with billing enabled.

I immediately disabled the billing on them, changed password, and checked to see If they were in the Projects list, and they are not.

as seen in the picture, the last one is my project. but I don't know anything about them. the last number on them makes me even more suspicious, incase this is done to many people and it's like an ID for my account.

[image: screenshot of my google cloud console]

So I want to ask experienced firebase users, does this normally happen? can you tell me a way to remove them?

Comment: The name are typical for firebase auto generated project names - if you create projects in the firebase console it defaults to names of that form

Comment: @Elemental so does firebase create projects randomly with random names? I have even never heard of the word "liquid-streamer" or "disco-sector" or "nth-fiber". they seem too meaningful to believe they are generated, and why would google give such meaning full names by it self? I am not that well experienced on this platform.

Comment: When creating a project with the default settings and left the name as "My First Project", Firebase/GCP chooses a random project id like `liquid-streamer`. Now that's the explanation about the names but not about how those were created. In this case I would recommend to reach support to get more info about that in case you didn't create those projects https://firebase.google.com/support.